# How can we enable private endpoint for Pay as you go Model Endpoints in Azure AI

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-marketplace, azure-ai

Following [Meta Llama 2 7B product](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/metagenai.meta-llama-2-7b-offer?tab=overview) in Azure marketplace, I deployed it in azure ai service. AFter the deployment I got my endpoint as something like

`https://mydemo-llama-serverless.eastus2.inference.ai.azure.com`

I already enabled the private endpoint for my [Azure AI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-studio/how-to/configure-private-link?tabs=cli) but those endpoints can give the private endpoints for the domain `privatelink.api.azureml.ms` and `privatelink.notebooks.azure.net` however my Pay-as-you-go deployment having the domain as `inference.ai.azure.com` which is still public.

Question:
How can I make my inference endpoint for my Pay-as-you-go model deployment as private?

If the answer is not yet supported can someone guide me on any workaround or when we can expect this feature?